# Merge different repositories into one

Tags: mercurial, merge, repository

I have two different Mercurial repositories, each with its own history.
Is there a way to merge the two into one repository that would also have complete history of both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pull one into the other with the `-f` flag:

```
> cd path\to\repo1
> hg pull -f path\to\repo2
> hg merge

.... deal with merge conflicts ....

> hg commit -m "Merge with repo2"
```

Comment: To ensure there will be no merge conflicts, simply move all files in one of the two repositories into a subfolder before the merge: `mkdir foo; hg rename * foo`.

Comment: For example I have two repos repo1 and repo2. I want to import repo2 into repo1 so that the directory structure will be like this:
repo1/src/com/example/HelloWorld.java
repo1/repo2/src/com/example/

Comment: You could do as Martin suggested.  From within `repo2` you'd execute `mkdir repo2; hg rename * repo2; hg commit -m "Move repo2 files into a subfolder"` then follow my instructions above (although there would be no merge conflicts unless you already have a `repo2` folder in `repo1`)

Comment: Combining answer from Martin and Steve is exactly what I want. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe. Try this approach:

1. Clone repo #1
2. Create a set of patches using `hg export` from repo #2
3. Import the patches into the clone using `hg import`

This will fail when the two repos have common files. The solution here will be to apply the failing patches using `hg patch`.

Background: Mercurial creates a checksum for each changeset. This strong cryptographic checksum contains the modification date, the user name, checksums of the parent changeset(s) and the patch.

This means if you try to copy a changeset from one repo to another, this will fail simply because the parent changeset(s) can't be found. It's not easy to add the parent changeset because of the checksums.